# Unable to affect other objects in ListView aside from the first one, in Django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I am trying to create an upvote system in my Django site using ajax so it would not refresh when users click the upvote button. In my site's main page with the listview of all the posts, I am able to get the ajax and the upvote request to work, but only for the top post. No matter if I click on an upvote button from another post, it would only register the effect on the top post. Where did I go wrong?
Below is my code.

**models.py**

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL #this is the user model

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #many to one relationship where many posts can be tied to one user
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) 
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='trade_images', blank=True, null=True) 
    upvotes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='upvotes')
    total_upvotes = models.IntegerField(default='0')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('main:post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}) #returns the url for individual posts

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content


class Upvote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='upvoted_user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='upvoted_post',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + ':' + str(self.post)
```

**views.py**

```
# list of all posts
class post_list_view(ListView):
    
     model = Post
     template_name = 'main/home.html'
     context_object_name = 'posts' # this is called from the html as 'for post in posts'
     ordering = ['-date_posted'] # minus to reverse the date posted, so newer posts show up on top
     paginate_by = 5 #sets pagination per page

          return context
     


def upvote(request):
     if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
          result = ''
          id = int(request.POST.get('postid')) 
          post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id) #grabbing the selected post using postid
          new_relation = Upvote(user=request.user, post=post) #storing the upvote relation between user and post using Upvote model arguments - 'user' and 'post'
          if post.upvotes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists(): #checking if user already has upvote relations with post by filtering user and post
               post.upvotes.remove(request.user) #remove upvote relation from post 
               post.total_upvotes -= 1 #minus 1 total_upvotes from post
               result = post.total_upvotes #storing the new total_upvotes into result
               Upvote.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post).delete() #filtering user and post and deleting the upvote table
               post.save()
          else:
               post.upvotes.add(request.user)
               post.total_upvotes += 1
               result = post.total_upvotes
               print('create upvote')
               new_relation.save()  
               post.save()

          return JsonResponse({'result': result }) # return the new total_vote count back to html as json
```

**template.html**

```
<div id="upvote-section" class="card-footer">
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="{% url 'main:upvote-post' %}" method=POST>
        {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="upvote-btn" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">Upvote</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" id="upvote-btn" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">Upvote</button> 
    <p id="total_upvotes">
        {{ post.total_upvotes }}
    </p>
    <a href="{% url 'main:post-detail' post.id %}" class="card-link"></i> Comment</a>
    {% if post.user == user %}
    <a href="{% url 'main:post-update' post.id %}" class="card-link">Edit</a>
    <a href="{% url 'main:post-delete' post.id %}" class="card-link" style="color:red">Delete</a>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
{% else %}
Upvotes ({{ post.total_upvotes }}) Please login to upvote or comment.
{%  endif %}  
</div>
```

**script/ajax**

```
<script>
        $(document).on('click', '#upvote-btn', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '{% url "main:upvote-post" %}',
           data: {
             postid: $('#upvote-btn').val(),
             csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
             action: 'post'
           },
           success: function (json) {
             document.getElementById("total_upvotes").innerHTML = json['result']
           },
           error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(err)
           }
         });
       })
     
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your AJAX script. Specifically in your data object,

```
data: {
         postid: $('#upvote-btn').val(),
         csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
         action: 'post'
       }
```

Since you're selecting the `postid` using `$('#upvote-btn').val()`, you are always sending back the value for the first upvote button.

Selecting anything in your DOM by using it's id, will return the FIRST element that matches the specified id. This is why it's recommended you don't use same ids for more than one element in your DOM.

Now that we know what the problem is, here's ONE possible way to fix it:

You can have the `upvote-btn` as a class instead of id in your template, so that every upvote button has a class called `upvote-btn`.
So your script becomes something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.upvote-btn', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '{% url "main:upvote-post" %}',
       data: {
         postid: e.target.value,
         csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
         action: 'post'
       },
       success: function (json) {
         document.getElementById("total_upvotes").innerHTML = json['result']
       },
       error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
        console.log(err)
       }
     });
   })
```

Note, the changes are in the first line of the script, we have changed the selector from `#upvote-btn` to `.upvote-btn` because we have previously discussed converting upvote-btn to a class instead of an id.

And we have also changed the `postid` in your AJAX call from `$('#upvote-btn').val()` to `e.target.value`

Comment: you are a god my friend.

Comment: sorry but how could i also get it to change the selected post's html? the code for that is currently `document.getElementById("total_upvotes").innerHTML = json['result']` which only affects the first post still. I have tried to change it to using class, but not able to get the results. Thanks!

Comment: @cdub It's the same problem. Every p element has the same id. What you could do instead is have the paragraph's `id = total_upvotes_for_{{post.id}}` and then when you go to update it, you could do something like `document.getElementById("total_upvotes_for_"+e.target.value).innerHTML = json['result']`

Comment: you are the best bro i owe you one